# Editor Template in a post call is not passing model correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi Folks someone help me 2 days ago with a solution to generate several textboxes from a list in the domain model with razor using an editor template, and i put a little js for make it a little more dynamic and all, but when i make the post call to the action method in the controller, it dont refresh the values inside the text fields,  i will put some codes here maybe you know what the problem is.

this is want i want to achieve 
[image: a form to send messages up to ten recipients]

```
//AntiBot Field
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    public int ContentItemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Recipients")]
    public List<Recipient> Recipients { get  
                                            { return new List<Recipient> 
                                                {
                                                    new Recipient { Name = "", Email = "" },                                                        
                                                    //x10
                                                }; 
                                             } 
                                      }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nachricht")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Recipient{
    [Display(Name = "Recipient Name:")]
    public string Name  { get; set;}

    [Display(Name = "Recipient Email Address:")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set;}
}
```

each one of this input fields have this properties
[image]
so i have up to ten fields and each one of this fields has an id Recipient_(1_10)_Name/Email

this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Share"))
 { 
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ContentItemId)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer, new { @class = "b2a534d1" })        
     <p>Hi: @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Salutation) @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Firstname) @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Lastname)</p>            
     <table border="0" style="padding:5">
        <tr>
            <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title): </td>
            <td class="editor-field">@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Title)

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description): </td>
            <td class="editor-field">@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Description)

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message)</td>
        </tr>             
        </table>
        <table >                       
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Recipients)
        </table>
        <table>                   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" id="add-recipient" class="small button">Add Recipient</a></td>            
                <td><input type="submit" class="button med primary" style="float: right;" value="ABSENDEN" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>      
 }
```

and this is my recipient

```
@model PetterLetter.Application.Models.Recipient


<p class="recipient"> Name: @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Name) Email: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email) </p>
```

and after i debug the solution this is what i get from the model of the view.

[image]

this recipient should have the values entered in the input fields of the editor template??

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a dynamically loaded form, and the solution can be gleaned from [Phil Haack's post.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

The upshot is, when you load more than one of these forms, you must assign them a different index value (not [0] every time).

I've solved this by using the hidden field for the collection Index, and assigning it a unique value. It can be anything in reality, like a date time string, as long as the index value is also used in each of the input names. Read the linked post, particularly the non-sequential indices section.

Comment: they are not 0 everytime they increase at each item  :S i will read the link anyway

Comment: Ah. One thing that might help is to look at the form data that was posted back. The problem might not be in the model binding. If you have chrome developer tools or firebug, and turn on your debugger, as soon as the debugger stops the page, inspect the request form data. If the form data being posted back looks good, then it might be the model binder or something else.

Comment: Just noticed, your model's Recipients collection doesn't seem to have a setter. Might want to add that.

Comment: i used glimpse to see the request and this is what i got in the model object http://i40.tinypic.com/soomyb.png

Comment: @brightwarden that was it! i wanna kill myself for something sooooooooooooooooo simple :( total day wasted, but well at least is done thank you very much!

Comment: how can i declare it if i just put set; at the end of the get bracket? told me Error 5 'Models.ShareContentItemModel.Recipients.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: Hmmm... I'd just use the auto-implemented property (e.g., { get; set; } and add an initializer in the constructor (e.g., this.Recipients = new List<Recipient>();) At least until I ran into the next problem :)